# Enable Other Microsoft Product Update on Windows Update in Windows Server Core 2022

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2022

As you know in Windows Desktop and Windows Server with UI, in Windows Update, we have one option like below

```
Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows.
```

and we can enable or disable this option to update for example SQL Server or PowerShell or etc, automatically.

So I want similar feature in Windows Core 2022, but I cannot find this option in [Windows Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-servicing), How to enable this feature in Windows Core 2022?

Comment: I think this question must move to serverfault, but I do not know how to move this question, any moderator can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Microsoft Update rather than the default Windows Update.
Microsoft Update includes updates from Windows Update and from
Office Update, in addition to updates for other Microsoft products
and for third-party device drivers.

See the post
[Switch server core to use Microsoft Update instead of Windows Update](https://serverfault.com/questions/1004420/switch-server-core-to-use-microsoft-update-instead-of-windows-update),
where the accepted answer suggests this PowerShell code:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager).AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")
```

To check if it worked, you could use the following commands :

```
$MUSM = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager"
$MUSM.Services | select Name, IsDefaultAUService
```

Comment: Thanks, how to check it? How to know the command run successfully?

Comment: I expanded my answer.